# Proof about exp function, inequality

Tags: calculus

I need to proof the inequality, that $e^x > 1+x^2$ for positive $x$?

Thanks

Taylor doesn't work

Easy to proof for  (0,1]. So one can assume x>1 in his proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x > 0$, then
$$
e^{x} - 1 - x^{2}
  = x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \sum_{k=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{k!} 
  \geq x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{6}
  = x(1 - \tfrac{1}{2}x + \tfrac{1}{6}x^{2}).
$$
The quadratic $1 - x/2 + x^{2}/6$ has discriminant $(\frac{1}{2})^{2} - 4\cdot\frac{1}{6} < 0$, and since it's positive at $x = 0$, it's positive for all real $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the Taylor expansion
$$ e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \cdots. $$

If $x \leq 2$ then $x \geq x^2/2$ and so $e^x > 1 + x + x^2/2 \geq 1 + x^2/2 + x^2/2 = 1 + x^2$.

If $x > 2$ then $x^3/6 > x^2/3$ and $x^4/24 > x^2/6$ and so $e^x > 1 + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + x^4/24 > 1 + x^2/2 + x^2/3 + x^4/6 = 1 + x^2$.